# mysql stored procedure - order by column index

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm wrining a stored procedure in mysql and I want to use a parameter for the column index in the order-by-clause. I've tried the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `testProc` (
  IN $sortColNum INT
)
BEGIN
SELECT id, title, date, sticky, published, created, updated, content
FROM news 
ORDER BY $sortColNum DESC;
END
```

The stored procedure doesn't throw an error, but the result is unsorted. When i use the column index as a parameter in a prepared statement, it works fine. Why doesn't it work in a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work.  Your `$sortColNum` is treated as a constant rather than a column reference.

You have two choices.  One is to use a `prepare` statement.  The other is to explicitly list the columns in a `case` statement:

```
order by (case $sortColNum
              when 1 then id
              when 2 then title
              when 3 then date
              when 4 then sticky
              . . .
          end)
```

This method has the downside that all values are converted to the same data type (presumably strings).  You might want to do explicit conversion yourself, in the event that the conversion affects the sort order.

Comment: The `ORDER BY CASE ...` method also has the downside that it can't use an index for sorting. This will probably not be a big deal, but it should be noted.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `testProc`(IN sortColNum INT)
BEGIN
    SET @query = CONCAT ('SELECT id, title, date, sticky, published, created, updated, content
FROM news ORDER BY (',sortColNum,') DESC');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Comment: And, *Why doesn't it work in a stored procedure?* without a prepared statement?

Comment: When you use `ORDER BY sortColNum DESC` with a value of 'title' (for example), in the actual query it becomes `ORDER BY 'title' DESC` - it orders by the constant string 'title' instead of the column named title.